# Find text in innermost curly brackets starting with word with given substring

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Consider the following text:

```
{\Largefont\it Hello world!} Some text. {   \Hugefont \sl Thanks.}
```

I am trying to write a regular expression which will:

1. identify innermost curly brackets in the full text, and
2. check if the first word in the identified block of text starts with '\' and has a substring 'font' in it.

The regex

```
re.compile(r'\{\s*[^{}]+\}')
```

does the first part of the job. How do I accomplish the second part? In particular, I do not want `\Largefont\it` to be treated as a single word but rather as two separate words `\Largefont` and `\it`. The expected output is:

```
{\Largefont\it Hello world!}
{   \Hugefont \sl Thanks.}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [`(?<={)\s*\\[^\\]*font[^{}]*(?=})`](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a positive look ahead that will ensure your incoming data follows the pattern. Here is the regex you can use,

```
(?<=\{)(?=\s*\\[^{}\\]*font)[^{}]+(?=\})
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdIgxP/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\{)` - Positive look behind to ensure the text is preceded by `{` character
- `(?=\s*\\[^{}\\]*font)` - Positive look ahead to ensure content inside curly brackets starts with optional white space then `\` then first word contains `font` in first word followed by optional characters other than `{` or `}`
- `[^{}]+` - Actually captures the intended text
- `(?=\})` - Positive look ahead to ensure captured content is contained within closing curly bracket

Comment: [`(?<=\{)(?=\s*\\[^{}]*font)[^{}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/3) does not get you the required contents from the innermost curly brackets only.

Comment: @Gurman: I deliberately didn't put that end considering that was enough but taking your point updated to include a positive lookahead at end to ensure } and end of input. Check my updated regex and [link](https://regex101.com/r/CdIgxP/3)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, thank you for nice explanation and good regex solution.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks for your support and I am glad to hear your encouraging words :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi. Thank you. Worked like a charm for my full document.

Comment: @pmath: So pleased to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<={)\s*\\[^\\]*font[^{}]*(?=})
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/2/)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<={)` - positive lookbehind to make sure that the current position is immediately preceded by a `{`
- `\s*\\` - matches 0+ whitespaces followed by a `\`
- `[^\\]*font` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `\` followed by the substring `font`
- `[^{}]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `{` nor a `}`. **This subpart makes sure that you are getting the content of innermost curly brackets**
- `(?=})` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is immediately followed by a `}`

Comment: Your regex fails for this [case](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/5/) It selects unintended text other than inner most brackets

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi [Just add `{}` in the negative character class to avoid that issue](https://regex101.com/r/xN1Im1/6)